# Sum All Odd Fibonacci Numbers, freecodecamp challenges

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, fibonacci-sequence

Recently I took a challenge on freecodecamp to solve the given problem:
"Sum All Odd Fibonacci Numbers"

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Sum All Odd Fibonacci Numbers of number <input type='number' id='val' min="0"/>
<button onclick="getOutput()">get Result</button>
<span id="output"></span>
<script>
  function sumFibs(num) {
    if(num < 2) {
      return num;
    }
    var old = 0, now = 1, sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      if(now <= num) {
        if(now % 2 !== 0) {
          sum += now; 
        }
        temp = now;
        now = now + old;
        old = temp;
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
  function getOutput() {
    var val = document.getElementById('val').value,
    output = document.getElementById('output')
    if(isNaN(val)) {
      alert('not a number')
      return
    }
    output.innerHTML = sumFibs(val);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like it. Short and efficient.

Comment: thanks @barryCarter, i want to understand how this can be further optimise

Comment: I think you've nailed it. I would argue that any time spent making this more efficient would be wasted.

Answer (score 3):

This code is great! However, I have a few suggestions. I will put the suggestions in this code segment, marked with "CR".

```js
function sumFibs(num) { // CR: improved formatting
  if (num < 2) {
    return num;
  }
  let old = 0; // CR: ES6 variables, split assignments
  let now = 1;
  let sum = 0;
  let temp; // CR: declared temp
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    if (now <= num) {
      if (now % 2 !== 0) {
        sum += now; 
      }
      temp = now;
      now += old; // CR: augmented assignment
      old = temp;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

- Great job on solving the challenge with iteration!
- Many IDEs put a space after `for` and `if`
- Only declaring one variable per statement looks better, and can be less confusing in languages like C
- `let` is scoped. If you use `var` with 2 `for` loops that declare `i`, it will be declared twice, but this doesn't happen with `let`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thank you for supplying an answer to this question that has been unanswered for some time. Could you please [edit] to expand upon what is great about the code? Also, in what ways does it have “improved spacing”- spaces after keywords? And for the sake of the OP and others can you explain the benefits of es6 variables?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thanks for the advice! I'm new to code review, so I didn't really understand how it works. I'll edit the question.